# Randomly extracting files from subfolders in main folder

Tags: python, dictionary

mat` files from the main folder which contains seven subfolders. Each folder is named with class number.

```
import glob
import os
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np
DATASET_PATH = "D:/Dataset/Multi-resolution_data/Visual/High/"     
files = glob.glob(DATASET_PATH + "**/*.mat", recursive= True)
class_labels = [i.split(os.sep)[-2] for i in files]

for label in range(0, len(class_labels)):
    class_labels [label] = int(class_labels[label])
```

`files` variable contains the following:

[image]

Class labels contains the following:
[image]

I want to ask couple of things:
1) when I read the `.mat` files, it comes if `dict` and each dict contains different variable name. I want to know how can I read the `key` and assign to the array?

```
array_store=[]
for f in files:
    mat = hdf5storage.loadmat(f)
    arrays = np.array(mat.keys())
    array_store.append(arrays)
```

[image]

2) `files = glob.glob(DATASET_PATH + "**/*.mat", recursive= True)` Is it possible to randomly read the specific amount of files from each folder inside the main folder? like 60% for training and 40% testing?
**UPDATE**
I have tried what @vopsea sugeested in Answer. 
The output looks like that for `train` variable. 
[image]

How I make the final array of images each files foy Key 1 - 7 (array (256 x 256 x 11 x total number of images))and labels (total number of images x 1 )? Labels will be same as key values, for example for all the files associated with Key 1 (188 files) will have label 1 (188 x 1).

**UPDATE**
resolving issue of making label and accessing key without key name.

```
import os
import random
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

DATASET_PATH = "D:/Dataset/Multi-resolution_data/Visual/High/"

train_images = []
test_images = []
train_label = list()
test_label = list()
percent_train = 0.4
class_folders = next(os.walk(DATASET_PATH))[1]
for x in class_folders:
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x))
    random.shuffle(files)
    n = int(len(files) * percent_train)
    train_i = []
    test_i = []
    for i,f in enumerate(files):
        abs_path= os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x,f)
        mat = hdf5storage.loadmat(abs_path)
        if(i < n):
            train_i.append(mat.values())
            train_label.append(x)
        else:
            test_i.append(mat.values())
            test_label.append(x)

    train_images.append(train_i)
    test_images.append(test_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Could you explain a bit more what you want in question 1? What is being appended? I might be misunderstanding, but it's easy to read unknown key, value pairs

```
for key, value in mat.items():
    print(key, value)
```

2) I did this without glob. Shuffle the class files and slice them into two lists according to training percent. Probably best to have the same number of files for each class (or close) so training doesn't favor one especially.

```
import os
import random

DATASET_PATH = "D:/Dataset/Multi-resolution_data/Visual/High/"

train = {}
test = {}
percent_train = 0.4

class_folders = next(os.walk(DATASET_PATH))[1]
for x in class_folders:
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x))
    random.shuffle(files)
    n = int(len(files) * percent_train)
    train[x] = files[:n]
    test[x] = files[n:]
```

**EDIT 2:**
Is this what you mean?

```
import os
import random
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

DATASET_PATH = "D:/Dataset/Multi-resolution_data/Visual/High/"

train_images = []
test_images = []
train_label = []
test_label = []
percent_train = 0.4
class_folders = next(os.walk(DATASET_PATH))[1]
for x in class_folders:
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x))
    random.shuffle(files)
    n = int(len(files) * percent_train)
    for i,f in enumerate(files):
        abs_path= os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x,f)
        mat = hdf5storage.loadmat(abs_path)
        if(i < n):
            train_images.append(mat.values())
            train_label.append(x)
        else:
            test_images.append(mat.values())
            test_label.append(x)
```

**EDIT 3:** Using dict for simplicity

Notice how simple it is to run through the images at the end. The alternative is storing two lists (data and labels) and one will have many duplicate items. You then have to through them both at the same time.

Although depending on what you're doing with this later, two lists could be the right choice.

```
import os
import random
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

DATASET_PATH = "D:/Dataset/Multi-resolution_data/Visual/High/"

train_images = {}
test_images = {}
percent_train = 0.4
class_folders = next(os.walk(DATASET_PATH))[1]
for x in class_folders:
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x))
    random.shuffle(files)
    n = int(len(files) * percent_train)
    for i,f in enumerate(files):
        abs_path= os.path.join(DATASET_PATH,x,f)
        mat = hdf5storage.loadmat(abs_path)
        if(i < n):
            train_images[x] = mat.values()
        else:
            test_images[x] = mat.values()

for img_class,img_data in train_images.items():
    print( img_class, img_data )
```

Comment: for the first part what I mean is the key name of each time .mat read is will different. What I want to do is read the .mat file (which is an image of size 256x256x11) and put the image into array. Finally, I want to put all the images in one array thats why append is used

Comment: I have update the 2nd part of the question with what you have suggested

Comment: See my edit. I'm not familiar with .mat format. You want to save the image data itself in a list where each index has a different class?

Comment: Yes its quite similar to that. But the name `image` is name for each file. Thats what I am asking in first part Is it possible to do that whatever the Key name comes, i get its value.. Also, needs to make `class_labels` variable. Like if read the data of folder 1 or Key 1 `class_label` will have 1 for that..For example:
at the end class_labels will be [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,6 7]

Comment: Just run  the update code, `files` contains the file names only. We need to concatenate it with the `DATASET_PATH ` and `class_folders ` to make a complete path to load with `hdf5storage.loadmat`

Comment: For `class_label` will have to use vaiable `x`

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand the structure you're trying to create..
I did fix the abs path problem you mentioned two comments above.
Could you post a short example of what you want the structure to look like with a description of each piece of data? Like show the list/dict elements and labels.  Not sure I can help much more at this point.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the path. I have added the `train_label = list()` and then after `train_i` I have added `train_label.append(x)`. What i want to do is first of `class_folders` run to each folder one by one. For example: When it read all the files in `1` folder and put in variable of train_i it should also make `train_label` variable add 1 for each file. If there is 5 files in folder 1 then `train_label` will have [1,1,1,1,1]. Than it will start reading folder 2 and it have 2 files `test_label` will [1,1,1,1,1,2,2]. Therefore I have added `train_label.append(x)`.. is it correct?

Comment: Secondly, `train_i.append(mat['image'])`..reading every .mat file doest have same key name. so i can't fix `'image'` key name.. Is it possible to extract without key name?

Comment: I have resolved these issues. Now when i run the code `train_images.append(train_i)` it makes 7 sets of files and each set contains images `len(train_images)` is 7. However, I want to to make it without set . it should stack it like this 256x256x11 x total number of images

Comment: See my new edit 2, is that what you want?
IMO it makes more sense to use a dict or nested list here instead of a list for labels and a list for image data, that's why my first answer used a dictionary.
Try the next edit 3 after to see what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199602/discussion-between-vopsea-and-aadnan-farooq-a).